# Data fetching from snowflake using laravel +ODBC connection showing error

Tags: laravel, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

I am connecting the snowflake database using Laravel. But while fetching data from table showing the below error. I am storing json content in the table using the datatype VARIANT

```
SQLSTATE[SL009]: <<Unknown error>>: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]No columns were bound prior to calling SQLFetch or SQLFetchScroll (SQLFetchScroll[0] at /build/php8.2-upKkUu/php8.2-8.2.6/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:556)
```

i am using the below sql

```
$select  = "select parse_json(ACCOUNT_DETAILS) from POC.TEST.TESTING_TABLE2 where ACCOUNT_DETAILS:gender='Male'";
     $res= DB::connection('snowflake')->select($select);
```

Comment: Hi - it might be helpful if you updated your question with the code and SQL statement you are running - as well as your connection details (with any identifying information redacted)

Comment: Does your query run fine on Snowflake UI if you test it?